# Removing objects from an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have this array containing simple objects

```
var data = [
{type:1, owner:"jason"},
{type:1, owner:"john"},
{type:2, owner:"jason"},
{type:2, owner:"alice"},
{type:2, owner:"bob"},
{type:2, owner:"clark"},
{type:1, owner:"david"}
]
```

i am trying to loop through the array and removing only elements with type:1. This is what i tried.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  if(data[i].type === 1){
     data.splice(i,1)
  }
}
```

Would it be stupid of me to assume that after that loop runs that all type 1 elements will be removed from the array. After running this in chrome dev tools, the array still contains {type:1, owner:"jason"} and all type:2's were left untouched as expected. what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to just decrement `i` after splice

```
i--;
```

BTW I would like to just use filter and assign result to same `data` variable like bellow

```
data = data.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.type !== 1;
})

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Wow! that worked like magic. Thanks @Mritunjay. I think i prefer this filter solution. Any idea how well this performs on huge large data sets?

Answer (score 1):

you should run i-- after splice, because splice resize the array,the array index immediately changed after removing.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
  if(data[i].type === 1){
     data.splice(i,1);
     i--;
  }
}
```

Comment: Index 0 must be treated differently though.

Comment: index 0 will be -1 after i--, but will be 0 again when current loop ends after i++.

Comment: thanks @worldask. guess my understanding of the splice method is limited.

Answer (score 1):

Decrease i by 1 whenever you splice your var data.
Because that means the array list of objects is becoming smaller and so the index position shifts.

Since you aren't decreasing by 1,  you start with the jason at position 0 and then directly jump to jason at position 2. WHY does this happen? Since you sliced an object in the beginning, your index position shifted like this.

First loop: i=0

```
    var data = [
    {type:1, owner:"jason"},//position 0
    {type:1, owner:"john"},//position 1
    {type:2, owner:"jason"},//position 2
    {type:2, owner:"alice"},//position 3
    {type:2, owner:"bob"},//position 4
    {type:2, owner:"clark"},//position 5
    {type:1, owner:"david"}//position 6
    ]
```

Second loop i=1

```
    var data = [
    {type:1, owner:"jason"},//SPLICED
    {type:1, owner:"john"},// position 0
    {type:2, owner:"jason"}, //position 1
    {type:2, owner:"alice"},// position 2
    {type:2, owner:"bob"},//position 3
    {type:2, owner:"clark"},//position 4
    {type:1, owner:"david"}//position 5
    ]
```

Comment: +1 for the explanation. This is exactly what i wanted to know. @Amna Irfan thanks :)